# Downloading Hadoop Data from other PC

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, remote-access

I have Hadoop v2.6 installed in my one PC in Ubuntu OS 14.04. I have added lots of unstructured data using **Hadoop -put** command into HDFS.

Can someone tell me how to download this data from another PC which is not in Hadoop Cluster using the Web User Interface provided by Hadoop??

I can access the data from other PC by typing in the address bar of browser **(the IP address of HDFS server):Port Number**

Like this: **192.168.x.x:50070**

The problem is, I am not able to download the data as it gives the error "Webpage Not Available". I also tried other browsers, but still no luck.

Comment: It seems your ip address is wrong. Check eith your correct ip address. Try to ping the ip from terminal.

Comment: Is the PC you are trying to download on is from same network?

Comment: Yes the 2nd Pc is on same network and the IP is also correct and pinging.

Comment: What file type are your trying to download? Does the web UI list the file you need to download? When do you get `Webpage Not Available` error? Is it when you click the file to view or after clicking `Download the file`? Also, can you download the file in your namenode system? If you cannot, then the file might be corrupted while uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Port 50070 is the default name node port. You should try port 14000 which is the default HttpFS port. If it still doesn't work try using the example from the [manual](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/ServerSetup.html):

```
http://192.168.x.x:14000?user.name=babu&op=homedir
```